# Search around a given location with Algolia on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, algolia, android-studio-2.3

I am developing a navigation application which uses Google Maps. I am trying to implement "my nearby user location" with the application.

I want to use the Algolia service for searching geo-locations using GeoFire with Android & Firebase.

I have successfully stored latitude and longitude information in my Algolia index with their documentation's guidance.

But I don't understand  how I can automatically fetch the list and map the location (like in sample project of algolia instant search) based on my current location without entering the place name or any address. Here's my current code:

```
com.algolia.search.saas.Query query = new com.algolia.search.saas.Query().setAroundLatLng(new com.algolia.search.saas.Query.LatLng(lat,lng)).setAroundRadius(5000);

index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
     @Override
     public void requestCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, AlgoliaException e) {

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem you are facing? Are you blocked on what to do next? The jsonObject you get in `requestCompleted` is going to be something like:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "firstname": "Jimmie",
      "lastname": "Barninger",
      "objectID": "433",
      "_highlightResult": {
        "firstname": {
          "value": "<em>Jimmie</em>",
          "matchLevel": "partial"
        },
        "lastname": {
          "value": "Barninger",
          "matchLevel": "none"
        },
        "company": {
          "value": "California <em>Paint</em> & Wlpaper Str",
          "matchLevel": "partial"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "page": 0,
  "nbHits": 1,
  "nbPages": 1,
  "hitsPerPage": 20,
  "processingTimeMS": 1,
  "query": "jimmie paint"
}
```

In Java you can access it like `jsonObject.getObject("hits")`.

Are you using [instantsearch-android](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android) or [algoliasearch-client-android](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android) ? You should use the `instantsearch-android` one, is easier to link the search with your UI. [Here's](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/tree/master/icebnb) an example with GoogleMaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, for replying.  My problem is base on my loction lat lng search nearby location.

In the qiven example there is search done by giving input in search bar but my need is search by my current location. I am successfully receiving lat lng.

Comment: When i run the sample app for instantsearch i getting this error on icebnb

Error:(53, 17) error: registerResultListener(AlgoliaResultsListener) is not public in Searcher; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: I see. How do you integrate the sdk, with gradle ? Indeed, at some point there was an issue with `registerResultListener(AlgoliaResultsListener)` not being public but it was fixed [here](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android/commit/ffac65c73ec7da1e86cde9c8f8db3a54ab58b163)

Comment: But what are you trying to do with the results? Showing them on a map, list, etc ?

Comment: My problem is 

automatically fetch the list and map the location (like in sample project of algolia instant search) based on my current location without entering the place name or any address.

That's it.

Pls bro help me. :)

Comment: @thofiq-ahmed, we fixed the problem you were encountering with `egisterResultListener(AlgoliaResultsListener)`. Now if you refresh(clean + build) the project, it should work. If you look in the `Icebnb` example, in `MainActivity` you'll see something like: 

`searcher.setQuery(new Query().setRestrictSearchableAttributes("city", "country", "name").setFacets("room_type", "price"));`



If you change that to `searcher.setQuery(new Query().setAroundLatLng(new AbstractQuery.LatLng(lat, lng)).setAroundRadius(5000))` it should work

Comment: It would be easier if you just share the code so I can have a better understanding of what you're trying to do :)